# What does the batting strike rate signify?

Tags: cricket, terminology, statistics

If player has batting strike rate of 300 what does that mean?

If bowler has strike rate of 20 then we say he has taken 20 balls to take a wicket. what can we say in case of batsmen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The batting strike rate signifies the rate at which a batsman scores runs. We can see the strike rate of batsmen for limited overs cricket is far higher than test matches, where they'll score runs slowly.

By definition, batting Strike Rate is the total number of runs a batsman will score if he faces 100 balls. If a batsman has batting strike rate 300 means, he scored runs three times than the number of balls he faced.

It's easy to calculate batting strike rate with the below formula,

> Batting S/R = (No. or runs scored/No. of balls faced) x 100